# what is AWS signature Authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, authorization

I recently saw this in Postman and many time I hear this,
How does AWS signature Authentication differ from Basic Authentication other than sending credentials as plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic authentication is built into the HTTP protocol. When you use basic authentication, you actually send the complete credentials, typically a username and password. They are base64-encoded and sent in an HTTP Authorization header that looks like this:

```
Authorization: Basic ZGVtbzpwQDU1dzByZA==
```

If you [decode](https://decodebase64.com/) this, you'll see that it's `demo:p@55w0rd`. Both username (demo) and password (p@55w0rd) are sent, and anyone who can intercept the transmission in the clear can decode the authorization header to retrieve the username and password. Typically you'd be sending over HTTPS (TLS/SSL) so interception should not be an issue.

Signed requests are a different thing. In this case you send your request with one half of the credentials which in AWS is the access key. You then [sign the request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html) using the second half of the credentials, which in AWS is the secret key, and you send the calculated signature with your request. The secret key is never sent. The server that receives the request takes the access key that you sent, looks up the associated secret key, signs the request payload that was received, and compares that signature to the one you sent.

Both give you an authentication mechanism, but there are some advantages of AWS signed requests over basic authentication:

- you never send the full credentials
- the request is tamper-evident, so cannot be modified in flight by an attacker
- the request is time-limited so cannot be replayed 5+ minutes later